# The second monitor has not detected

Tags: display-resolution

I am running 16.04.1, and I purchased a (Samsung LED monitor 18.5 LS19F350HNWXXL) and connected it to my (HCL ME 9525) laptop. I replaced the original screen of my laptop with that Samsung LED monitor. Everything was working fine in the beginning, and it was working on its optimal resolution (i.e 1366*768), but now it has been three days that my screen is not detected and not working in its optimal display.

It only works in 1024*768 resolution, which is not comfortable or compatible for my work. I talked to Samsung customer support and they told me that I have to upgrade my graphic driver software.

I have installed both Ubuntu and Windows on my laptop and when I updated the graphic driver in Windows it worked well, but when I tried to update the graphic driver in Ubuntu it said I already have most updated graphic driver installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
[sudo] password for anurag:
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...Done
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

**What I have tried:**
I have gone through so many answers mostly on askubuntu.com and many other websites, but could not find any genuine answer that could work for me. I have also installed `Intel graphic driver updater for 16.04` but that also did not work. I have been trying to solve this problem from two days but still did not find out any solution that's why I had to ask this question on this forum.

[screenshot of lspci command to show GPU model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd7eG.png)

[screenshot of lspci |grep VGA command to show GPU model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D943J.png)

Comment: You should add your GPU model to the question.

Comment: Hi Bruni, Thanks for responding. I do really appreciate it. I have added two screenshots of lspci command showing the GPU model of my laptop and in software settings - Details it is showing this "Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly help me please

Comment: You will have to wait for somebody with experience with your graphics card...

Comment: Is there anyway to set the resolution of a screen to 1366*768 pixel in terminal.

Comment: It's been a long time to get solution of this problem. If I change my linux distro like "mint" or "opensuse" then could it help me?